# OpenGL: Control drawing order of 2D animation tree

Tags: opengl, graphics

I have a 2D animation organized as a tree of shapes. However, I need a drawing order different than either a depth-first or breadth-first traversal from the root. Is there a way to control the final draw order?

I need to find a way to do this without breaking the parent-child inheritance in the tree. For instance, when I draw the tree, I need each child to inherit translations and rotations from its parent and then pass those translations and rotations on to their children.

I can think of various ways to handle this, but it does not seem like a unique problem so I am wondering if there is an OpenGL-specific solution.

Comment: Have you thought of doing 2 passes?  First pass you update the matrices for each item.  Second pass you draw the scene in whichever way you want.

Comment: @Robinson: That's exactly what I was thinking when I said I could think of various ways to handle this. I was just wondering if OpenGL had any functionality for situations like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL does not care about your objects. It's just a drawing API.

If your drawing order is different from the parent-child relation, one solution would be to split up the calculation of transformations and the drawing in two steps.

In the first step you traverse your tree top-down and store in each node the transformation of the parent objects. In the second stage, you traverse the objects in rendering-order and render them using the transformation from step 1. The traversal mainly depends on how you store/define your drawing order.

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind to handle this myself. I was wondering if OpenGL had any native functionality for handling this. Seemed like a common problem so I wondered if it had a built-in solution.